# Trouble reading config file with perl's Config::Simple module and die

Tags: arrays, perl, config, die

I'm attempting to read a simple configuration file in perl with the Config::Simple module.  One of the lines in this configuration file is an array, which looks like this:

```
# EXTENSIONS TO TRANSFER
extensions = "\.mpg\$","\.txt\$"
```

I can successfully read this array (and verify the data) like this:

```
@ext = $cfg->param("extensions");
print @ext;

.mpg$ .txt$
```

I run into a problem if I attempt to do some basic error checking, specifically, if the parameter doesn't exist in the configuration file, die.  However, if it successfully parses the array, it just prints out the memory location rather than the actual contents:

```
@ext = $cfg->param("extensions") || die "Failed to read 'extensions'";
print @ext;

ARRAY(0x9403788)
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you clearly demarcate precedence?

```
(@ext = $cfg->param("extensions")) || die "Failed to read 'extensions'";
print @ext;
```

Or does using the lower precendence `or` work?

```
@ext = $cfg->param("extensions") or die "Failed to read 'extensions'";
print @ext;
```

See [Perl Idioms Explained - && and || "Short Circuit" operators](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=301355) for details.

Comment: If I make either change, it works.  Thanks for the help (as well as the link to details)